# Scheduled instance of report sending stale data

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

I have a scheduled instance emailing to a user. The instance works fine and user gets email. But the data in the report attached to the email is stale. It is missing item codes that do show up in the report if you go view it directly in web browser at BO server.

If I create a new instance scheduled to send to me - data looks up to date and good to go. If I add myself on the instance sending stale report and re-run the instance, I also get the stale version.

I'm worried about how whatever this is could be impacting other reports/users in the company without our knowledge. And also want to fix this one instance.

Is there some caching or other options that could be causing this? Why is the instance sending stale data?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Turns out someone added record select formulas to the base report but did not re-create the scheduled instance. I looked at meta data from CI_INFOOBJECTS etc to see the record select formula on the instance. It does not match the updated record select on the base report.

This highlights a great best practice to keep in mind in this environment. KEEP YOUR FILTERS OUT OF CRYSTAL REPORTS! Keep your record selection and data transform logic inside SQL server in stored procs or views. That way you can update your report filter criterias without have to re create every scheduled report instance after every little report change :)